# What am I doing wrong in this bash script?

Tags: bash

I've been fumbling about with this bash script for a while now but I'm not familiar enough with bash scripts to figure out the problem. Here is my script:

```
    #!/usr/bin/bash

# Battery level warning script

NOTIFIED=0

while true; do

    BATTERY_LEVEL=$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity)
    STATE=$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status)

    echo "beep"
    # notify user of battery level
    if [ $STATE == "Discharging" ] ; then
        echo "Discharging"
        if [ $NOTIFIED -lt "1" && $BATTERY_LEVEL -lt "50" && $BATTERY_LEVEL -gt "10" ]; then
            echo "Battery >10%, < 50%"
            sudo -u korgan DISPLAY=:0 DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus notify-send "Battery low warning" "Battery level is ${BATTERY_LEVEL}%" --icon=battery-low
            NOTIFIED=1
        elif [ $NOTIFIED -lt "2" && $BATTERY_LEVEL -lt "11" && $BATTERY_LEVEL -gt "5" ]; then
            echo "Battery >5%, <11%"
            sudo -u korgan DISPLAY=:0 DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus notify-send "Battery very low warning" "Battery level is ${BATTERY_LEVEL}% Use ac power now, or shutdown is imminent - close applications"  --icon=battery-caution
            NOTIFIED=2
        elif [ $NOTIFIED -lt "3" && $BATTERY_LEVEL -lt "6" ]; then
            echo "Battery <6%"
            sudo -u korgan DISPLAY=:0 DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus notify-send "Battery critical warning" "Battery level is ${BATTERY_LEVEL}% Shutting system down now"
            NOTIFIED=3
        fi
    elif [ $STATE == "Charging" ]; then
            echo "Charging"
        NOTIFIED=0
    fi

    if [ $BATTERY_LEVEL -gt "60" ]; then
        echo "Battery > 60%: waiting 10 secs"
        sleep 10
    else
        echo "Battery <=60%: waiting 5 secs"
        sleep 5
    fi
done
```

The goal is to get notify-send warnings when my battery is discharging and at certain levels of charge.  The error I get is

```
./battery_check.sh: line 16: [: missing `]'
./battery_check.sh: line 20: [: missing `]'
./battery_check.sh: line 24: [: missing `]'
Battery > 60%: waiting 10 secs
```

Comment: Is it possible that `STATE` is not set at all?

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) automatically detects common issues like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
if [ $NOTIFIED -lt "1" && $BATTERY_LEVEL -lt "50" && $BATTERY_LEVEL -gt "10" ]; then`
```

to

```
if [ "$NOTIFIED" -lt "1" ] && [ "$BATTERY_LEVEL" -lt "50" ] && [ "$BATTERY_LEVEL" -gt "10" ];  then  ....`
```

Comment: Beat me to it! Yes, you must enclose each expression in between [ ] and use the && operand in between them

Comment: Further explanation: `[` is an ordinary command, not special shell syntax. `&&` *is* special syntax that joins two commands, running the second when the first succeeds. `[` has a quirk, though: the last argument *must* be `]`, which is why you get that error instead of a "command not found" error for whatever the value of `$BATTERY_LEVEL` is. (Replace `[` with `test`, which has no mandatory final argument, to see the command-not-found error appear.)

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax errors on 16th, 20th and 24th lines. It should be

```
if [ $NOTIFIED -lt "1" ] && [ $BATTERY_LEVEL -lt "50" ] && [ $BATTERY_LEVEL -gt "10" ];
```